# Material ui input background color override standard label

Tags: css, material-ui

I use react material ui and i want to change the background color of input (standard) the problem is the label who get override by the background color when the input is NOT selected.

[Input selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZZJZ.png)

[Input not selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9OcC.png)

This is what i tried

```js
  overrides: {
    MuiInput: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF0000'
      }
    },
   }
```

My input

```js
  <TextField />
```

the only way i found to make it work is to add transparency to the color, is there an other way  ? I want to change the background input only not all component

Comment: the color code is not a var, it's a string, try adding quotes. `backgroundColor: "#D8E5E1"`

Comment: Yes, it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<TextField/>` Component you can try to override the `<TextField/>` root styles.

You can check an example -> [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-cache-8zett?file=/src/index.js)

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTextField: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: "#FF0000"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the backgroundColor only in the field ?